# Unifiable Prolog Terms

Tags: syntax, prolog

Are the two terms [a,b,c,d,e] and [[X] | [b,c,d,e]] unifiable? I need confirmation I think they are not because you cannot get [X] = a in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to unify with `[X | [b,c,d,e]]`, not `[[X] | [b,c,d,e]]`, i.e. you can get `X=a`, not `[X]=a`.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is correct: `[X]`, that we can rewrite as `.(X,[])` cannot be unified with the atom `a`.

We can rewrite `[X|[b,c,d,e]]` as `.(_G231,.(b,.(c,.(d,.(e,[])))))`, i.e. `[X,a,b,c,d,e]`.

You can inspect see the shape without syntax sugar using display/1.

Answer (score 1):

if X needs to be enclosed in a list for some reason, you will not be able to have this unify (as described by chac).  but you can use the append predicate to get a match:

```
?- append([X], [b,c,d,e], [a,b,c,d,e]).
X = a
```